# I can spring mvc mapping resources with external smb server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, smb, jcifs

i need mapping spring resources with external server, but my server connection is with samba,

is possible use:

with user and password??

I use jcifs with spring mvc for images in my rest services to return array bytes, but tag video not support array bytes then i like mapping in resources mvc.

Help me pls

Comment: Your english is rather hard to interpret, but if I am understanding you, you want to read in a file from an SMB share?  As long as the drive is mapped locally somehow, why would Java/Spring care?  The OS would handle reading the files.

Comment: Is not local, i have user and password and domain: \\domain..., i want read the file with spring mvc resources mapping. I return byte[] with response body but tag video not recognized

Comment: Again, what I am saying is to map the drive locally.  This can be done on both Windows and Linux.  The operating system will take care of dealing with the username/password.  From the code perspective it is just another drive/map.